# Not able to get the WCF Result in Angular JS with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, wcf, angularjs

I want bind the values from WCF service to controller. but am not able to bind the values from WCF result. but if i use online webservice means its working perfectly.
please help me. i wasted lots of time. i share the code and screen which is worked.

This is My HTML Code.

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
<ul><li ng-click="alertSwap()">click </li></ul>
<ul><pre>data {{data|json}}</pre></ul>
</div>
```

This is my Angular JS Code

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource']);
fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, stockData) {
    $scope.alertSwap = function () {
       stockData.query('somedata')
                    .then(function (result) {
                       $scope.data = result.data;

                    }, function (result) {
                        alert("Error: No data returned");
                    });
    }
 });

fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope', 'Data'];
fessmodule.factory('stockData', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
var factory = {
        query: function (value) {
                // here you can play with 'value'
                var data = $http.get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json');
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }    
    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

This is perfectly working Online webservice.

[image]

This my webservice which is not working my WCF Service.

[image]

Comment: Did you inject stockData -- just checking, because in inject i saw Data

Comment: @madhured i tried inject method also but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
query: function (value) {
                // here you can play with 'value'
                var data =[];
**$http.get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json').success(response)
          {
          data = response;//Or value=response.Data;
          };**
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Instead of your's ..

Comment: Thambi indha method ellam try panniyachu Work aagala raja. how can i call the ".svc" extension service in angular JS ?

Comment: Annaa !! vaankanna.. vanakamnaa!   `value=response.Data` Intha way'a try pannuneenkalaanaa?? Our coding loking good'nkana ....  Check your URL na .. :P !!

Comment: And please check the data is empty or not empty by using debugger or break pint

Comment: i attached the 2nd screenshot which the result came in response, but using in a function throwing undefined.